# How to update a object inside array which is present in a object which is present in an array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've got a document like this,

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "comments": [
            {
                "mail": "raj@gmail.com",
                "Comment": "This product well worth the money"
            }
            {
                "mail": "janu@gmail.com",
                "Comment": "Excellent Product"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "comments": [
            {
                "mail": "raj@gmail.com",
                "Comment": "This product well worth the money"
            }
            {
                "mail": "janu@gmail.com",
                "Comment": "Excellent Product"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I need to change only the `Comment` with `mail` "raj@gmail.com" which is inside the `comments` array of the object having the `id` "1".

So the hierarchy looks like,

1. Find Object with `id:1`
2. Find an object with `mail:raj@gmail.com` inside `comments` array,
3. Update the `Comment` of the particular Object

This is the query I tried to update but doesn't work

```
  modal.findOneAndUpdate(
      { id: 1, comments: { mail: "raj@gmail.com"} },
      {
        $set: {
          "comments.$.Comment": "New Comment",
        },
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `comments: { mail: "raj@gmail.com"}` to `'comments.mail': "raj@gmail.com"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`arrayFilters`](https://database.guide/how-the-arrayfilters-parameter-works-in-mongodb/) to update the nested document in the array as well.

```
db.collection.update({
  id: 1
},
{
  $set: {
    "comments.$[comment].Comment": "New Comment",
    
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "comment.mail": "raj@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eB01YE8rQBk)